# Como duplicar los elementos de una lista excluyendo los extremos en python

Tags: python

Tengo las siguientes listas en python

```
lista_x = [2,3,4,5]
lista_y = [6,7,8,9]
```

Intento replicar el elemento actual (excluyendo los extremos) a la siguiente posicion. De modo que obtenga algo similar a esto:

```
lista_x = [2,3,3,4,4,5]
lista_y = [6,7,7,8,8,9]
```

Tengo este codigo, pero no he podido lograr mi objetivo

```
for i in range(len(lista_x)):
    if(i != 0 and i!=len(lista_x)):    #Exluyendo extremos
        lista_x.insert(i,lista_x[i])    #Agrega el valor actual 
        lista_y.insert(i,lista_y[i])
```

Comment: Quieres duplicar todos los elementos excluyendo los extremos?

Comment: Si, se podria decir que eso es lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Esta pregunta tiene pintas de tratase de un ejercicio que busca que obtengas una solución *ingeniosa* al problema planteado.

En general, cuando haya que procesar una lista, lo primero que debes conocer son los distintos métodos y funciones que operan con listas y buscar si alguno de ellos puede serte de utilidad. Uno de los más potentes es **zip** con el que puedes mezclar listas. Con un poco de perspicacia, se puede ver que si haces un `zip` de la lista consigo misma, puedes llegar a algo muy próximo a lo que necesitas:

```
>> lista = [2, 3, 4, 5]
>> resultado = zip(lista, lista[1:])
```

El resultado:

```
>> print(list(resultado))
[(2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Lo que falta es **concatenar** todas esas tuplas y obtendrías la solución. Para concatenar podrías crear un bucle que fuera añadiendo cada tupla, pero hay otra forma más directa usando la función `sum`:

```
sum(zip(lista, lista[1:]), ())
```

El elemento inicial es la tupla vacía `()` al que se va concatenando (sumando) las tuplas que obtenemos mediante `zip` para obtener una tupla. Como nos piden una lista, habrá que **convertir la tupla en lista**.

Poniendo todo en su sitio, la **solución** es:

```
resultado = list(sum(zip(lista, lista[1:]), ()))
```

Comment: Muy bien trabajado +1

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu explicacion del metodo zip.

Answer (score 4):

Para no complicarte la vida, crea una función que recorra la lista desde la segunda posición hasta la ante ultima posición. Esto se hace colocando después de la lista entre llaves **`[1:-1]`**. Esta sintaxis lo que denota es que se copie la lista desde la segunda posición hasta el final, excluyendo el último item.

Recuerda que en Python los indices comienzan desde el **`0`**, asi que la segunda posición es el **`1`**.

El **`-1`** seria la ultima posición

## Utilizando el método `append`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

lista_x = [2, 3, 4, 5]
lista_y = [6, 7, 8, 9]


def no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto(lista):
    resultado = []   # creamos una nueva lista para trabajar
    resultado.append(lista[0])  # agregamos a la lista el primer item

    # recorremos desde la posición 2 hasta la ante ultima posición
    for item in lista[1:-1]:
        # añadimos a la lista dos veces el item actual.
        resultado.append(item)
        resultado.append(item)

    resultado.append(lista[-1])  # agregamos a la lista el ultimo item
    return resultado


print no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto(lista_x)
print no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto(lista_y)
```

## Utilizando el método `insert`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto2(lista):

    resultado = lista[:]  # hacemos una copia exacta de la lista original

    # creamos un rango desde el indice 1 hasta el ante último.
    for indice in range(len(lista))[1:-1]:
        # Debemos multiplicar por dos el indice al que queremos insertar el
        # valor, ya que la lista va creciendo y los item moviendose una
        # posicion en cada iteración.
        resultado.insert(indice * 2, lista[indice])

    return resultado


print no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto2(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto2(['uno', 'segundo', 'tercero', 'ultimo'])
print no_entiendo_para_que_es_esto2([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
```

## Utilizando `sum` sobre tuplas generadas a partir de una iteración

```
def solucion3(lista):
    return sum([(item, item) for item in lista], ())[1:-1]


print solucion3([2, 3, 4, 5])
# (2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)

print solucion3([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
# (2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6)

print solucion3(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
# ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd')

print solucion3(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c'])
# ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'c')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Habia visto esa notacion muchas veces en python [1:-1], pero hasta ahora no sabia a que hacia referencia

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias, me funcionó tu metodo. Pero tambien encontré en stack overflow ingles una funcion que lo resolvió. Por si alguien llega a utilizar algun dia esto, aqui lo dejo.

```
lista_x = [i for i in lista_x for _ in (0, 1)] 
lista_y = [i for i in lista_y for _ in (0, 1)]

#Eliminamos el primer elemento y el ultimo (excedentes generado por la funcion anterior)
lista_x.pop(0)
lista_y.pop(0)

lista_x.pop(len(lista_x)-1)
lista_y.pop(len(lista_y)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque no usar la función repeat de la biblioteca numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = [1,2,3,4]                    # una lista cualquiera
b = np.repeat(a,2)               # duplicas la lista
c = np.delete(b,[0,len(b)-1])    # eliminas el primer y último elemento
print c                          # imprimes la lista
[1 2 2 3 3 4]
```